# i'm so curious about this part. "how"

Tags: grammar

“But remember how you went eighty-seven days without fish and then we caught big ones every day for three weeks.”

1. what does "how" menas as in "Remember how you went ~ " ?

Comment: It is a way of giving emphasis: “You should remember that …

Comment: thank you for replying. can i see that meaning in online dictionary? what can i type it and then find the meaning you answered ?

Comment: Please note that you should always say where you found a quotation that you ask about.

Comment: i'll keep it mind. thank you for your tip.

Answer (score 3):

One of the meanings of *how* is *the way in which.*

If you remember that something happened, you know that it did happen. If you remember *how* it happened, you recall what it was like to live through that experience.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it means "the fact that":

> But remember **the fact that** you went eighty-seven days without fish...

The function of this sentence is only to remind the listener that something happened, not the manner.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **how**
> *conjunction*
> **1 b :** that
> *// told them how he had a situation*

Comment: wow, finally makes sense now. thank you so much!